# Return the value of Scope ID to label

Tags: c#, sql, label, scope-identity

I am new to development and I want to show the last key id of an inserted row into a label. The code I have does not return the value into the label.

Code I have:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Users"].ConnectionString))
        {

            var cmd = "INSERT INTO Quote (Customer, Date)VALUES (@Customer, @Date);SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
            using (var insertCommand = new SqlCommand(cmd, conn))
            {
                int newID;
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer", TextBox12.Text);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now);
                conn.Open();                    
                newID = (int)insertCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                Label1.Text = newID;

            }
        }
```

Comment: What you've got looks like it should work - its straight from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx). Possibly try add a `SET NOCOUNT ON` before the `INSERT INTO` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like it should work.  The only thing to change is the last line.  Add `.ToString()` to the end.

```
Label1.Text = newID.ToString();
```

Comment: Your code looks fine; I do something similar all the time.  I suspect your problem isn't with this block of code.  Try setting the label text elsewhere and see if the label text changes.